# The Weird Interpretation for Contravariant and Covariant Vector

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, mathematics

I have seen the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/541822/covariant-vs-contravariant-vectors?noredirect=1&lq=1) for related topics, and it makes sense to me for the trivial contranvariant expression for a vector,
$$\pmb{v} = v^i\hat{e}_i\tag{1}$$
and it is said that if the base $\hat{e}_i$ double its length, the component $v^i$ should change *contraryly* to halve its length to make the vector *invariant*.
However, the formal definition of *contravariant vector* by a transformation should be,
$$x^{\alpha} \rightarrow x'^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial x'^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}x^{\beta}\tag{2}$$
$$A^{\alpha} \rightarrow A'^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial x'^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}A^{\beta}\tag{3}$$
It seems to me that, in formal definition, the component in contravariant manner would change corresponding to the change of coordinates since **$x'^{\alpha}$ is in numerator in (3)**, isn't the component changing conversely to the change in coordinates?
Please help me figure it out!

Comment: Related : [Geometrical representation of Contravariant and covariant vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646091/geometrical-representation-of-contravariant-and-covariant-vectors/646123#646123).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you just have the reasoning reversed. Suppose that $x'^\alpha = 2 x^\alpha$. Then all of the contravariant components double, just as you said. But a vector is left invariant because *all the basis vectors become half as long*. Formally, that's because the basis vectors carry a lower index. Intuitively, it's because a basis vector represents the distance you need to go to increase the coordinate by $1$. If you double the coordinates, then you only need to go half as far, so the basis vector is halved.